# Why is my SSD reported as only 128KB in size

Tags: ssd, bios

I have a SanDisk mSATA SSD that is 16GB in size. In one computer it is reported as having only 256 512 byte blocks (thus being only 128KB in size), in both BIOS and Linux. In another computer it is fully working. I've tried different BIOS settings, but to no avail.

Any ideas on what is wrong and what I can do about it?

Comment: It would seem to be a limitation of the BIOS, so you should first look for a BIOS upgrade. If this does not solve it, the SSD manufacturer may offer a patch for incompatible BIOS firmware.

Comment: AFH mentioned BIOS upgrade or patch. Even if there is none that solves the problem, there is still a chance (and risk) to take. I once had a piece of hardware (I cannot remember what it was exactly) which didn't work with my motherboard even with newest BIOS. It turned out that the motherboard manufacturer had stopped updating this model BIOS, yet they made some more updates to the newer, similar model. The BIOS was modular. I extracted updated module and replaced its old version in the abandoned BIOS. Such procedure requires research, it can brick the motherboard. It went well for me.